# how to validation email in codeigniter only use domain "gm.ac.id"?

Tags: php, codeigniter

how to validation email only use domain @gm.ac.id. i try but validation its not working.

this is code

```
public function email_check($email)
    {
        if (valid_email('email@mail.ugm.ac.id'))
        {

            return TRUE;
        }
        else
        {
            $this->form_validation->set_message('email_check', '%s gunakan email ugm');
            return FALSE;
        }
    }
$this->form_validation->set_rules('email', 'email', 'required|callback_email_check');
```

please help me what to do.

thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Valid_email has no way of knowing what domains it should allow or not.

An easier way would be:

```
$this->form_validation->set_rules('email', 'email', 'required|valid_email|callback_email_check');
```

This way you pass to `email_check()` only those emails which are validly constructed. Now you are just left to check the domain. Something like:

```
public function email_check($email)
{
  return strpos($email, '@gm.ac.id') !== false;
}
```